# Scraping data from a password protected website using vba User-defined type not defined

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I would like to import data from a password protected website(https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Ports/Home.html), i do have the username and the password.

I've tried this VBA code made by Dick in this website: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/11/29/html-tables/ but it doesn't work and get stuck every time i adjust it.

It get stuck here : [image: Compile error: User-defined type not defined]

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Home.html"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.UserName.Value = "username"
.Password.Value = "password"
.submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Port/tangermed/Dashboard.html"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
clip.PutInClipboard
Sheet1.Select
Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close 'er up
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I really appreciate any help from you. Thank you.

Comment: The word is "scrape", not "import".  :)

Comment: ok, i'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the required reference like this:

> You need to include the **MSForms** library.
>
> `C:\Windows\system32\FM20.DLL`
>
> Easiest way is to add a userform to your project.
>   <sub>([Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4a9c1ac-c5cf-4e92-83ec-5243fd73c5ff/dataobject-type-is-missing-from-excel-2000-vb-macro-programmer?forum=isvvba))</sub>

Or you can add the library by going:

Tools > References > Browse > `C:\Windows\system32\FM20.DLL`

Answer (score 2):

The type `DataObject` is undefined because MSForms is not present in your references.

You could use late binding instead to set some text in the clipboard:

```
With VBA.CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
  .SetText "1234"
  .PutInClipboard
End With
```